# Mutation Observer only get specific content

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="col">left</div>
   <div class="col">middle</div>
   <div class="col">right</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to get the nodes ONLY if INSIDE $('.col') a div of class "block" is included like:

YES for THIS:

```
$('.col')[1].append($('<div class="block">urgent</div>'));
```

but NO for THIS:

```
$('.col')[1].append($('<div class="different">dontcare</div>'));
```

my Observer looks like this:

```
 var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
                    console.log(mutation.addedNodes[i]);
                }
            });            
        });

    observer.observe(document, {
        childList: true,
        subtree:true,
        characterData:true,
        attributes:true        
    });
```

I am inside a chrome extension, but that should not really matter

Comment: Try it by your self ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified your code:

- `$('.col')[1].append` throw a TypeError, because you use jQuery function on DOM Node, use `eq` ,ethod
- Remove `for`, add `forEach`

I added the check for `.block` element in `mutation.addedNodes` NodeList via 
`addedNode.classList.contains('block')`

[My code](http://jsbin.com/vugiweribo/2/edit?js,console):

```
$(function () {
​
  'use strict';

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      [].slice.call(mutation.addedNodes).forEach(function (addedNode) {
        if (addedNode.classList.contains('block')) {
          console.log("I'm has a class block, whats next?");
        }
      });
    });            
  });
​
  observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree:true,
    characterData:true,
    attributes:true        
  });
​
​
  //Yes
  $('.col').eq(1).append($('<div class="block">urgent</div>'));
​
  //No
  $('.col').eq(1).append($('<div class="different">dontcare</div>'));
​
});
```

Comment: Your modification is incorrect due to the `addedNode` property may be changed later in the same `mutations` stack. In that case, by invoking `addedNode.classList.contains(...)` you are getting the final `addedNode` class list, which is an unsupposed behaviour.

Comment: A link to `classList` documentation would be great

Comment: Thanks for this! I use this with any changes for my problem!