# Get data change with observer mutation?

Tags: observers, mutation-observers

I'm trying to get the changed value of a HTML-Node.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if(mutation.addedNodes[0].data == "9"){
           dostuff();
        }
    }
}
```

But javascript returns only an object and no array of

```
addedNodes.mutation.addedNodes[0]
```

prints out:

> <TextNode textContent="9">

Where can I get the value of the changed HTML-Node?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution via [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828917/mutation-observer-only-get-specific-content)

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      [].call(mutation.addedNodes).forEach(function (addedNode) {
        if(addedNode.textContent == "9"){
           dostuff();
        }
      });
    });            
  });
```